# Does VPC Peering Cost you in same region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I am referring to the below document.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

So does VPC Peering Costs 0.01$ for Data Transfer-In?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it does. The same goes for Data Transfer OUT. So for each 1 Gb transferred you pay $0.02.

[image]
https://github.com/open-guides/og-aws#aws-data-transfer-costs

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful.

Comment: @Bharath This is NOT true. Only same-AZ data transfer is free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as stated by Sergey Kovalev, cross-region transfer does have a cost.

To add some valuable info for whoever reaches this question, since May 1st 2021, if the data transfer over a VPC Peering stays **within an Availability Zone (AZ)**, is free:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/05/amazon-vpc-announces-pricing-change-for-vpc-peering/